# flutter run -v continuously shows starting a new daemon, xx busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Tags: flutter, gradle, daemon

When running `flutter run -v` it is creating a lot of daemon processes and it never ends, thus resulting in freezing the system without completing the build. How to solve this ?

I have to forcibly terminate it, otherwise system will freeze.

[image]

`flutter doctor` runs fine. Here is the output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found out that if Windows Mobile Hotspot feature is turned on, this issue happens. So to avoid this issue, turn off Hotspot in Windows 10.